# Scientific notation in python

Tags: python

Hi I know that to print a number in a scientific notation I can do the following

```
"%.3e" % 123.456
```

will give

```
1.234e+02
```

however how can I obtain

```
12.34e+01?
```

Comment: `12.34e+01` is not scientific notation, what rules are you trying to accomplish when displaying numbers?

Comment: given digits a b c d e f g h  I would like to get the following transformation:
    0.abcdefgh -> 0.abc e+00
    a.bcdefgh -> a.bcd e+00
    ab.cdefgh -> ab.cde e+00
    abc.defgh -> ab.cde e+01
    abcd.efgh -> ab.cde e+02
    abcde.fgh -> ab.cde e+03

Comment: How do you determine when to use 2 as the exponent?

Comment: Also, your last example doesn't look correct.

Comment: yes sorry, you're right

Comment: @Revist I'm assuming the last example is a typo as it shows the same result as the previous, and what if the digits are outside of that range - such as `12345 *10^6`? or `*10^-6`

Comment: I basically want to see two places before the dot and anything else for bigger numbers

Comment: I will modify it a bit

Comment: 0.abcdefgh -> a.bc e-01 a.bcdefgh -> a.bcd e+00 ab.cdefgh -> ab.cde e+00 abc.defgh -> ab.cde e+01 abcd.efgh -> ab.cde e+02 abcde.fgh -> ab.cde e+03

Comment: so 12345 *10^6 -> 12.345e+09 and 12345 *10^-6 -> 1.234e-02

Comment: when I think about it the simplest solution to my problem would be to use scientific notation outside of the range of numbers 0.001 to 1000 so that 0.0001 -> 1.000e-04 and 10000 -> 1.000e+04. Within this numbers to use simple numbers with precision up to 3 decimal places.

Comment: I think I will manage to do this. Thank you for your help guys !

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: 12.34+02 actually *is* in [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), it's just not normalized according to either the scientific (1 non-zero digit before the decimal point) or engineering (1-3 non-zero digits before decimal point, exponent is a multiple of 3) conventions.

Answer (score 3):

For clarification, most usages of [Scientific Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) refers to [Normalized Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#Normalized_notation) which requires that the leading number be at least 1 but less than 10. In [Engineering Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#Engineering_notation), the exponent is a multiple of three.  These are the two most commonly used versions of Scientific Notation.

Comment: Not precisely an answer, but too important a clarification to bury in the comments, so I guess it had better stay where it is.